# Highlight table row and select radio input when table row clicked jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this : 
I want to select a radio input and highlight a table row when someone clicks somewhere in the table .Same idea is this but with radio input 
http://jsfiddle.net/FbHAV/2/

can I get some help ? What should I change in the Jquery?

HTML :

```
<table class="record_table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" />
    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" />
    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" />
    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" />
    </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
</tr>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.record_table tr').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
            $(':radio', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $("input[type='radio']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some jQuery code you've played with? Do you have a conceptual idea of what you need to do?

Comment: Same code as in here :http://jsfiddle.net/FbHAV/2/ just tried to change checkbox for radio

Comment: Don't link to code if you can avoid it. It's good practice to have a jsfiddle but users here should be able to look at as much of the necessary information as possible without leaving the page. So please copy a minimal snippet into your answer.

Comment: Done , added Jquery code.

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/FbHAV/459/. What is the problem?

Comment: ops :) forgot to add jquery to my page ... embarrassed
but now the row don't lose the background when i click another row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the major problem is that you forget to group the radio buttons, i.e

`<input type="radio" name="test" />`

Then this will work both when clicking on the radio button and the `<tr>` :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.record_table tr').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
            $(':radio', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $("input[type='radio']").change(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.record_table tr').removeClass("highlight_row");        
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
        }     
    });
});
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/48o1kycu/**